# Objective C Monitor.Wait or GetCurrentProcess().WaitForExit() equivalent

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa

i am trying to port some application from .NET to objective C.

Unfortunately for me , I don't have much time to learn the internals of iOS.

Is there any equivalent Objective C of

Monitor.Wait or GetCurrentProcess().WaitForExit() from .NET World ?

what i need is :

```
    int mail(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   // TCP communication to server goes here
   then i need to leave the process run. How to do it properly?
   Thanks.
}
```

Comment: You aren't going to be successful porting to iOS unless you have a basic understanding of the architecture of the system and the APIs of the platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to wait forever, use [`[[NSThread currentThread] sleepUntilDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSThread_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

If you want to wait until you receive a signal from another thread, use an instance of [NSCondition](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Reference/NSCondition_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSCondition).  E.g., -lock, -signal, -wait, -unlock.

Comment: Awful lot of rope in that answer... :)